# Agora Web SDK 4.11.1 user-published callback has no audio/video stream

Tags: angular, agora.io

I have an Angular project in which I am trying to implement the Agora Web SDK 4.11.1. So far, I have local tracks playing in my local player, but have run into issues subscribing to and playing the remote user's stream.

My code looks like this:

```
    async handleUserPublished(user:any, mediaType:any) {
        console.log("Agora User", user);
        await this.client.subscribe(user, mediaType);
        user.videoTrack.play('agora_remote');
    }

    handleUserUnpublished(user:any, mediaType:any) {
        this.client.unsubscribe(user, mediaType);
    }

    async startCall() {
        this.client.on("user-published", this.handleUserPublished);
        this.client.on("user-unpublished", this.handleUserUnpublished);

        [ this.agoraOptions.uid, this.localTracks.audioTrack, this.localTracks.videoTrack ] = await Promise.all([
            this.client.join(this.agoraOptions.appid, this.agoraOptions.channel, this.agoraOptions.token || null),
            AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack(),
            AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack()
        ])

        this.localTracks.videoTrack.play("agora_local");

        this.client.publish(Object.values(this.localTracks));

    }
```

So, everything seems to be going fine until it hits the second line of the handleUserPublished function. As you can see, I have a console.log of the user object, which looks fine except for:

```
audioTrack: undefined
hasAudio: true
hasVideo: true
videoTrack: undefined
```

After that, the this.client.subscribe() call throws an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: WebSocket.addEventListener:message ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

I've tried several things but seem unable to make it work.

What could the issue be? I'm pretty certain I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what for the life of me...

Comment: I have a same issue. Have you solve this ?